# Parsing a JSON date time with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, rest

I have a simple Spring MVC app which is accepting POST, GET and DELETE requests.
At the front end I have a simple JSP page which is importing AngularJS libaries and trying to parse the incoming JSON. I serialized the JSON with Jackson.
Below is the JSON response coming from my Spring MVC app and I want to get it with `ng-bind` like this:

```html
<td><span ng-bind="u.creationDate"></span></td>
```

This is how my JSON date time looks like:

```
{
  "dayOfMonth": 12,
  "year": 2000,
  "dayOfWeek": 2,
  "era": 1,
  "dayOfYear": 347,
  "chronology": {
    "zone": {
      "fixed": true,
      "id": "UTC"
    }
  },
  "yearOfEra": 2000,
  "centuryOfEra": 20,
  "yearOfCentury": 0,
  "monthOfYear": 12,
  "weekyear": 2000,
  "weekOfWeekyear": 50,
  "fields": [
    {
      "lenient": false,
      "minimumValue": -292275054,
      "maximumValue": 292278993,
      "rangeDurationField": null,
      "leapDurationField": {
        "unitMillis": 86400000,
        "precise": true,
        "name": "days",
        "type": {
          "name": "days"
        },
        "supported": true
      },
      "durationField": {
        "unitMillis": 31556952000,
        "precise": false,
        "name": "years",
        "type": {
          "name": "years"
        },
        "supported": true
      },
      "name": "year",
      "type": {
        "durationType": {
          "name": "years"
        },
        "rangeDurationType": null,
        "name": "year"
      },
      "supported": true
    },
    {
      "lenient": false,
      "minimumValue": 1,
      "maximumValue": 12,
      "rangeDurationField": {
        "unitMillis": 31556952000,
        "precise": false,
        "name": "years",
        "type": {
          "name": "years"
        },
        "supported": true
      },
      "leapDurationField": {
        "unitMillis": 86400000,
        "precise": true,
        "name": "days",
        "type": {
          "name": "days"
        },
        "supported": true
      },
      "durationField": {
        "unitMillis": 2629746000,
        "precise": false,
        "name": "months",
        "type": {
          "name": "months"
        },
        "supported": true
      },
      "name": "monthOfYear",
      "type": {
        "durationType": {
          "name": "months"
        },
        "rangeDurationType": {
          "name": "years"
        },
        "name": "monthOfYear"
      },
      "supported": true
    },
    {
      "minimumValue": 1,
      "maximumValue": 31,
      "rangeDurationField": {
        "unitMillis": 2629746000,
        "precise": false,
        "name": "months",
        "type": {
          "name": "months"
        },
        "supported": true
      },
      "lenient": false,
      "durationField": {
        "unitMillis": 86400000,
        "precise": true,
        "name": "days",
        "type": {
          "name": "days"
        },
        "supported": true
      },
      "unitMillis": 86400000,
      "name": "dayOfMonth",
      "type": {
        "durationType": {
          "name": "days"
        },
        "rangeDurationType": {
          "name": "months"
        },
        "name": "dayOfMonth"
      },
      "supported": true,
      "leapDurationField": null
    }
  ],
  "fieldTypes": [
    {
      "durationType": {
        "name": "years"
      },
      "rangeDurationType": null,
      "name": "year"
    },
    {
      "durationType": {
        "name": "months"
      },
      "rangeDurationType": {
        "name": "years"
      },
      "name": "monthOfYear"
    },
    {
      "durationType": {
        "name": "days"
      },
      "rangeDurationType": {
        "name": "months"
      },
      "name": "dayOfMonth"
    }
  ],
  "values": [
    2000,
    12,
    12
  ]
}
```

How can I properly display this date using AngularJS?

Comment: I use this span tag to get the date
<td><span ng-bind="u.creationDate"></span></td>

Comment: What information do you want to show in your screen? Only the date and in what format?

Comment: Can you tell me what type your "date time" field is in Java/Spring? Is it a `DateTime` from Joda or the Java 8 time library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your JSON response, it appears that you're using `DateTime` from the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, but you're missing Jackson support for Joda. You should add the following Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Joda, but you're using the Java 8 time API, you can add support by adding the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

If you're using Spring boot, this module will automatically be recognized and loaded by Jackson. When you run your application now, your JSON should be a simple UNIX timestamp:

```json
{"timestamp":1476709730090}
```

If you prefer a proper looking ISO datetime string, you can use the following properties in Spring boot:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-date-timestamps-as-nanoseconds=false
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

This will output something like:

```json
{"timestamp":"2016-10-17T13:13:41.386Z"}
```

---

Now you should be able to easily convert this with AngularJS/JavaScript by using:

```
obj.timestamp = new Date(obj.timestamp);
```

You can wrap this in a service/put it in `transformResponse` and afterwards you can use the [AngularJS date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to properly format your date, for example:

```html
<td><span>{{obj.timestamp | date:'short'}}</span></td>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I been looking for .

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code snippet:

```
var jsonString = '{"dayOfMonth":12,"year":2000,"dayOfWeek":2,"era":1,"dayOfYear":347,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":true,"id":"UTC"}},"yearOfEra":2000,"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfCentury":0,"monthOfYear":12,"weekyear":2000,"weekOfWeekyear":50,"fields":[{"lenient":false,"minimumValue":-292275054,"maximumValue":292278993,"rangeDurationField":null,"leapDurationField":{"unitMillis":86400000,"precise":true,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"durationField":{"unitMillis":31556952000,"precise":false,"name":"years","type":{"name":"years"},"supported":true},"name":"year","type":{"durationType":{"name":"years"},"rangeDurationType":null,"name":"year"},"supported":true},{"lenient":false,"minimumValue":1,"maximumValue":12,"rangeDurationField":{"unitMillis":31556952000,"precise":false,"name":"years","type":{"name":"years"},"supported":true},"leapDurationField":{"unitMillis":86400000,"precise":true,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"durationField":{"unitMillis":2629746000,"precise":false,"name":"months","type":{"name":"months"},"supported":true},"name":"monthOfYear","type":{"durationType":{"name":"months"},"rangeDurationType":{"name":"years"},"name":"monthOfYear"},"supported":true},{"minimumValue":1,"maximumValue":31,"rangeDurationField":{"unitMillis":2629746000,"precise":false,"name":"months","type":{"name":"months"},"supported":true},"lenient":false,"durationField":{"unitMillis":86400000,"precise":true,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"unitMillis":86400000,"name":"dayOfMonth","type":{"durationType":{"name":"days"},"rangeDurationType":{"name":"months"},"name":"dayOfMonth"},"supported":true,"leapDurationField":null}],"fieldTypes":[{"durationType":{"name":"years"},"rangeDurationType":null,"name":"year"},{"durationType":{"name":"months"},"rangeDurationType":{"name":"years"},"name":"monthOfYear"},{"durationType":{"name":"days"},"rangeDurationType":{"name":"months"},"name":"dayOfMonth"}],"values":[2000,12,12]}';

var ConvertedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

then you can use convertedJson as an object.

Let me know if any concerns.